# Excel add-in: Change version number in manifest for upload to Office Integrated Apps

Tags: xml, validation, office365, manifest, office-addins

I'm trying to update my excel add-in in the Integrated Apps section of Office 365.

I've uploaded my new manifest file and it successfully validates, however, it then throws error asking for updated version number. Thats fine - but when I update the version number, the manifest will not validate. Throws this error:

`Error # 1: Package Loading Failure: Provided add-in package was not understood. Please, make sure that the file being submitted is a valid Office add-in package.`

I'm changing these two values: `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>` and `<Version>1.0.0.0</Version>` in the manifest to `2.0` and `2.0.0.0` respectively.

Are there specific rules for these values that I may be missing? I cant find any info in the docs.. Any help is appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Don't change the `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>`. Change only the `<Version>1.0.0.0</Version>`

Answer (score 0):

The XML version attribute should be remained the same. So, the following line needs to be the same:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
```

And you may change the version attribute:

```
<Version>2.0.0.0</Version>
```